# EFCore Base entity model properties with private setters - migration bizarre behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

It seems private setters inside classes that entity models inherit from cause bizarre issues with EFCore migrations. Consider the following example, where there are multiple classes (`Bar` and `Baz`) that inherit from `Foo`. When running `Add-Migration` commands multiple times (add/remove the `private` modifier`), the generated schema is just wrong in multiple ways.

- Sometimes the `Created` property is set to be a dropped column
- Sometimes *all* the the `Created` properties are set to be removed (and not replaced/renamed with anything).

It's my understanding that EFCore tools don't really treat properties with private setters with any special care. Is this a wrong assumption? If so, why do *some* private setters work on base classes, but not others? I'm assuming this is a bug in the EF Tools, perhaps related to how it treats naming on properties, considering I have other properties with similar names in the model which might be confusing the tools

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Baz> Bazs { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo { }
public class Baz : Foo { }
public abstract class Foo
{
    protected Foo()
    {
        Created = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }
    public DateTimeOffset? Created { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Edit -> It seems private setters for DateTimeOffset cause EF Tools to never map them in base classes. However, I have a string property with a private setter with `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` attributes, along with `builder.Entity<Foo>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.RequiredStringProperty);` In that case, EF absolutely maps the property...but only with some of the classes that are inheriting from `Foo`.

Comment: I couldn't find a case when the `private` setter works. Also can't find a documentation stating that, but looks like properties w/o setters or with private setters are considered not mapped by default.

Comment: @IvanStoev They are sometimes definitely being mapped. I just ran another migration test, except I added `builder.Entity<Foo>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.Created);` In my project, one of the `Bars` wanted to drop the column Created, but not the `Baz`. To be more specific, the property doing this is a string with the `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` attribute. Somehow the behavior is different than `DateTimeOffset?`

Answer (score 1):

The EF core tools will map private setters of base classes only under certain conditions.

For example, if you have `builder.Entity<Bar>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.Created);`, then EF tools will map the `Created` property regardless of whether it has a private or public setter.

Comment: Same if you have `builder.Entity<Bar>().Property(x => x.Created);`. That's why I said *by default* in my first comment. Basically any fluent accessor to the property (except `Ignore` of course) is causing it to be mapped regardless of the private setter. Frankly I would avoid private setters (protected and internal setters have no such default behavior). Btw, I don't think this is tools behavior, but EF infrastructure default mapping.